# Sharepoint Multiple Values Column?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create a custom field with multiple values like it may store array variables.
also this field is not a lookup field.

what can be the field type that I should inherit from to achieve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPFieldMultiColumn may well be the class you're looking for. Here is the relevant MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmulticolumn.aspx

Good luck with it though, custom fields can be a pain in the ears at the best of times.

Comment: Thanks Stuart this is what I wanted to do. but I need to modify the RenderPattern of the field to display all the items in the display forms. can you provide me with a hint ?

Comment: The example on this page is a DisplayPattern for a multicolumn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544291.aspx

Comment: thanks for response, but my scenario requires to loop on all the sub columns of the MultipleColumn Column, can you tell me if that is possible

Comment: @Mina Samy: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure. The view schema (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439798.aspx) does have a foreach clause, but I haven't used it in that context myself.

Comment: Thanks Stuart for your great help. I'll check this and tell you if I find something